# git emergency - cannot merge of leave branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

heres a diagram of where i *think* i am

[link to image](http://awesomescreenshot.com/01b242y7cf)

[image: git woes]

1) i was on master and pulled and took everything : git pull origin master.
i may have done some git add . and git commit s that git status looks good.
but im always a little uneasy with these.

2) i did some work and went in a bunch of directions and it got too far from where i wanted.
im fairly certain i git add . and git commit regularly here.

3) i went back to master, git checkout master, but i dont think i pulled from origin.
i just created a new branch from master: git checkout -b branch2.

4) here is where i did work and didnt commit too much, but definitely at the end.
git add . and git commit -m "ready to merge".

5) so i git checkout master, git pull origin master, git status (things get weird for me here)
i think i only added the files i was certain i changed, but all these other files are present. 
i try to git merge branch2 but receive errors.
im a little panicky so i try t go back to branch2 to see my code for that, but cant.
thats when  realized i needed help.

help me stackoverflow, youre my only hope

Comment: using @franck post, i did a clean and am trying to merge but i dont have a gui merge tool that i am familiar with. so im still on my master branch trying to merge with branch2 and its telling me to fix it with a work tree or got commit -a. clearly im in over my head with this true multi developer environment

Answer (score 1):

Use `git log` to find out the SHA for (1) and `git checkout [the SHA]`

Then read up more on git and start again.

Answer (score 1):

A part of the solution :

You should try a **git clean -fd** to remove the files from other branches and see clearly what you need.

Then what is the errors you have ?

Comment: im a little worried about losing whats in #4, as thats the changes i need to merge. when i try git merge branch2, i get: 'merge' is not possible because unmered files, hint: fix them in work tree then git add/rm or git commit -a. main point is i dont want to lose git branch2

Comment: If you have done your **git commit** it's saved on your local repository.

You could also have a look on what is merged or not, then you can open your favorite merge tool (for my part I'm using Source Tree or vim) and fix/correct then git add the files you want.